# Working out digits of Pi.

Tags: pi

I have always wondered how the digits of π are calculated. How do they do it?

[image: Pi records]

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a question.

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_computation_of_pi

Comment: If you had read beyond the (ignored) copyright license of the image you show and linked the [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Record_pi_approximations.svg), you'd have immediately found Daryl's suggested link with detailled information (and a few others)

Comment: Here is Daryl's link for non-mobile browsers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_computation_of_pi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Chudnovsky algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudnovsky_algorithm), which just uses the very rapidly converging series $$\frac{1}{\pi} = 12 \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{(-1)^k (6k)! (13591409 + 545140134k)}{(3k)!(k!)^3 640320^{3k + 3/2}},$$ was used by the Chudnovsky brothers, who are some of the points on your graph.

It is also the algorithm used by at least one arbitrary precision numerical library, [mpmath](https://code.google.com/p/mpmath/), to compute arbitrarily many digits of $\pi$. [Here](https://github.com/fredrik-johansson/mpmath/blob/master/mpmath/libmp/libelefun.py#L178) is the relevant part of the mpmath source code discussing why this series is used, and giving a bit more detail on how it is implemented (and if you want, you can look right below that to see exactly how it is implemented).  It actually uses a method called [binary splitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_splitting) to evaluate the series faster.

Comment: One thing I'm not sure about: the mpmath source says that each term adds roughly 14 digits, but it's not clear if it's 14 more digits of $\pi$ or 14 more digits of $\frac{1}{\pi}$.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would go with $\frac{1}{\pi}$ since the terms of the _series_ are being implicitly referred to.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know how we do nowadays, but there is a formula due David Bailey, Peter Borwein, and Simon Plouffe in 1995 which it can be used to calculate the $i^{th}$ digit of $\pi$ in base 16:

$$\pi=\sum ^{\infty} _i\frac {1}{16^i}\big(\frac 4 {8i+1}-\frac {2}{8i+4}-\frac {1}{8i+5}-\frac {1}{8i+6}\big)$$

What I find interesting is we don't need to know the previous digits to find the $i^{th}$ digit of $\pi$. Nowadays there are a lot of variations of that formula, but it was a surprise when this formula was discovered, because until that time, the mathematicians thought be impossible to find the $i^{th}$ digit of $\pi$ without knowing the previous ones.

Comment: where to  put the n in formula

Comment: Are you sure this works on base 16? I just implemented a script that calculates this series and it plainly gives me a pretty good PI approximation in base 10

Answer (score 6):

From one of my favorite mathematicians,

$$
\frac{1}{\pi}=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{9801}\sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{(4n)!(1103+26390n)}{(n!)^4396^{4n}}.
$$

Looking [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html), we see some many formulae. Some of particular interest are:

$$
\pi=\sum_{k \ge 0}\frac{3^k-1}{4^k}\zeta(k+1),\quad \zeta(s)=\sum_{k\ge 0}k^{-s}.
$$

$$
\frac{1}{6}\pi^2=\sum_{k \ge 1}\frac{1}{k^2} \quad \text{via the Basel problem}.
$$

$$
\pi =\frac{3}{4}\sqrt{3}+24\int_0^{\frac{1}{4}}\sqrt{x-x^2}dx.
$$

$$
\frac{\pi}{5\sqrt{\phi+2}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k \ge 0}\frac{(k!)^2}{\phi^{2k+1}(2k+1)!},\quad \text{where } \phi \text{ is the golden ratio.}
$$

$$
\pi=\frac{22}{7}-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}dx.
$$

$$
\pi=4\sum_{1 \le k \le n}\frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{2j-1}+\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1)!}\sum_{i \ge 0}\frac{1}{16^i}\left( \frac{8}{(8i+1)_{2n}}-\frac{4}{(8i+3)_{2n}}-\frac{4}{(8i+4)_{2n}}-\frac{2}{(8i+5)_{2n}}+\frac{1}{(8i+7)_{2n}}+\frac{1}{(8i+8)_{2n}} \right),\quad \text{where } n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}, \text{ and } (x)_{n} \text{ represents the Pochhammer symbol.}
$$

$$
\pi = 2\left[\prod_{n \ge 0}\left(1+\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}p_n\right)}{p_n}\right) \right]^{-1},\quad p_n \text{ is the } n\text{th} \text{ prime number}.
$$

$$
\frac{2}{\pi}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}}}\cdots
$$

$$
\frac{\pi}{2}=\prod_{n \ge 1}\frac{(2n)^2}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}.
$$

Comment: Which mathematician?

Comment: @asmeurer Ramanujan. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one simple way to compute digits of $\pi$:

Recall that $\tan(\pi/4) = 1$.

Thus, we have $\arctan(1) = \pi/4$.

And, in particular, $4 \cdot \arctan(1) = \pi$.

You can now take the Taylor series expansion for $4 \cdot \arctan(x)$ and consider what happens when you evaluate it at $1$. Since the corresponding series (see, e.g., [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor%20series%204%2aarctan%28x%29)) is an alternating series decreasing in absolute value, you can evaluate however many terms you want, and then take an evaluation of the next term as a (somewhat crude) bound for your error.

Comment: This is an insanely inefficient way to calculate $\pi$.  Even if you have a calculator and only want to calculate 10 digits or so, it will take you forever.

Comment: I make no claims as to its efficiency; indeed, it takes about $700$ terms before you can accurately claim that the expansion begins $3.14\ldots$ I mention it strictly for its simplicity.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your answer to give the series explicitly, and to point out how slow it is.

Comment: Suit yourself, but do take a read of http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#editing.